# How can I make a custom horizontal table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, carousel

I have a master-detail style application that displays locations in the table view, and in the detail, shows various pictures from that location.

My current detail shows only the picture from the table view, but I want to be able to scroll left and right inside the `UIImageView` area to see the other pictures from the same location (which will be loaded from their URL's with SDWebImage)

How can I make a horizontal table view of UIImages that displays one image at a time? (Or should I just find a pre-built carousel library?)

Bonus points for the overachievers (Not necessary for best answer): How would I make another table view below the main UIImage that shows a small table of all the images, with a border around the selected photo? [More concerned with the custom table view implementation than the bordering]

Comment: This question could really use a decent answer.

Answer (score 4):

Check out UICollectionView and UICollectionViewController.  Provide your own UICollectionViewFlowLayout and set the scrollDirection property to UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal.

Collection View reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Collection View sample:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIScrollView` and enable `pagging`. The same for the small pictures preview but of course without pagging.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example and source code
[Exemple 1](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel)
[Exemple 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)